# How to handle XML Character reference in scala?

Tags: xml, scala, xml-serialization

I am trying to generate some XML on-the-fly in Scala.

I want to use a [numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) inside the XML and write out the resultant XML to an output stream.

Example:

```
val myXml = <body>Hello&#8198;World</body>
val writer = new java.io.FileWriter("test")
scala.xml.XML.write(writer, myXml, "utf-8", false, null)
```

8198 is unicode for a tiny space character.

After the above snippet is run, the contents of the file "test" are

```
<body>Hello World</body>
```

What I am expecting instead is,

```
<body>Hello&#8198;World</body>
```

**Edit**: Learnt how to escape XML in SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write:

```
import scala.xml.EntityRef
...
val myXml = <body>Hello{EntityRef("#8198")}World</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, with a minor change:

    EntityRef("#8198")